# Error when trying to import a crv file in a python file - [catkin project]

Tags: python, import, ros, publish-subscribe, catkin

**So i'm watching the following tutorial series** :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0difVe6GOw&list=PLAjUtIp46jDcQb-MgFLpGqskm9iB5xfoP&index=7

And in the 7th video(time 2:15) Im trying to import an **srv** file from a different folder in my **service_server_node.py** file.
in my import in the line **tutorials.srv** im getting the error **Import "tutorials.srv" could not be resolved Pylance**

And i have the following code in my **service_server_node.py** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from tutorials.srv import multiplier, multiplierResponse


def callback(request):
    return multiplierResponse(request.a * request.b)

def multiply():
    rospy.init_node("multiplier_service")
    service = rospy.Service("multiplier", multiplier, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiply()
```

I tried searching on the web but none of the things that i found worked. e.g. select interpreter etc

my projects file structure is the following:

```
tutorials
├── srv
│   └── multiplier.srv
└── scripts
    ├── publisher_node.py
    ├── subscriber_node.py
    └── service_server_node.py
```

I'm new to ROS and python so if i can help by providing more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your directory structure, you don't actually have a `tutorials.srv` file; instead you have `multiplier.srv`. Because of this the correct import should look like

```
from multiplier.srv import multiplier, multiplierResponse
```